# Windows Phone 8 developer unlocked but can't deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I used to test my application in my Phone but now it stopped working.
I can't seem to fix this error.

When I try to deploy, it says my phone isn't unlocked, but when I do the unlock process again, it says my phone is already unlocked.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might occur when you are trying to deploy the app when phone is on lock screen. Unlock the screen and try deploying the app.

**EDIT:**

You may try this one

Goto https://dev.windowsphone.com --> Dashboard --> Account --> Phones and remove your phone from the list. Then unlock your phone using "Windows phone Developer Registration" tool and try again. This might help.

Comment: The problem persists.

Comment: Eric, I have edited my answer and given another possible solution. Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the lock screen setup? Check the time out after setting. If this time has expired before your application is deployed it will fail due to the phone being locked.

Comment: I don't think it is related to the lock screen... It says I need to developer unlock my phone.